# Android toolbar navigation back button callback never called

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-navigation

I know there are a lot of question like this answered, but nothing I found works.

I have an activity (`MainActivity`) that takes care of showing different fragments. Also, in the activity, I have navigation drawer which I show only on one fragment (it is hidden on others).

**The problem is that toolbar navigation callback is never called**. Back button is showed, but click on it does nothing. Also (I don't know if it makes any difference) but user get to that fragment from another one in which I do same things as in this one except navigation back button is hidden.

XML for activity is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Included toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

Now, in activity I setup a toolbar and put a listener on its back button:

```
setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);
setTitle(getResources().getString("Some title"));
mainToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

In that specific fragment where I need back button I do this to show it:

```
if (this.context.getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    this.context.getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Fragment title"));          
    this.context.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);   
    this.context.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

And, since I don't want navigation drawer to be used/showed, in the fragment I call a method defined in the activity that executes this code:

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

On a specific fragment where you want to show back button simply add that fragment to backstack

add  this BackStack change listener to Activity

```
  @Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) 
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

to add to backStack you can use that line

if you pass true to addtoback stack then it will add in and backstack.

```
public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addtobackstack) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_enter, R.anim.fragment_exit);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, MainActivity.TAG);
    if (addtobackstack)
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);


    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: I am adding that fragment to the backstack already. Also, why should I do the same thing twice? First in `onCreate` and then in `onBackStackChanged`? And, also, every time backstack changes

Comment: ops i written is twice. you can only put that code in BackStackChange Listener

Comment: if you have 2 fragment and you want to back button enable when 2nd fragment show then you can check if there is object of second fragment then add it to back stack